# How does Sphero calculate velocity?

Tags: sphero-api, sphero

Sphero, a product of Orbotix, has the ability to calculate its velocity. How does it do this? Is it via rotations of the orb, or does it have another internal component which can derive its velocity?

NOTE: it can separate it into x and y vector components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses encoders on the wheels combined with algorithms in the control system.